# django1.3 static file problem

Tags: django-templates, django-forms, django-views, django-1.3

hi, I am new to django,I doing user authentication for my project,Well its works properly.

I have created a folder named 'static' in my projects root folder[now am in local devlopment] and necessary editing in setting.py ,

My first page[which contains a login form] displays the images and uses the css file successfully,If login success accounts/profile url map to a view ,which in turn 
leads to a template 'LoginSuccess.html' but which doesn't displays the images,and css files.

The problem is it doesn't fetches the images from static folder.
My command prompt looks  as follows

0 errors found

Django version 1.3, using settings 'SecondPrjt.settings'

Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

[20/Sep/2011 22:11:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5394

[20/Sep/2011 22:11:47] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3612


[20/Sep/2011 22:11:47] "GET /static/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150


**[20/Sep/2011 22:12:10] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 0**




[20/Sep/2011 22:12:10] "GET /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1930

[20/Sep/2011 22:12:10] "GET /accounts/profile/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2758

[20/Sep/2011 22:12:10] "GET /accounts/profile/images/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2764


[20/Sep/2011 22:12:10] "GET /accounts/profile/images/rss.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2761

[20/Sep/2011 22:12:10] "GET /accounts/profile/images/but1.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 2764

 Also am confused about the HTTP 302 which not related to the static files

**Note:** I use a base.html(calls css files,some images) which inherits all of my templates

**urls.py**
 (r'^$',login),
 (r'^accounts/profile/$',views.loginsuccess),
(r'^accounts/logout/$',logout),

Answer (score 1):

The problem I forgot to pass context while render
return render_to_response('user/LoginSuccess.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request)